# Cannot send arguements to FromJSON method of GoogleGson

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, gson

While sending arguments to `FromJson` method of `GoogleGson`,

> Cannot implicitly convert type. An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

error occurs.

I have tried changing argument types, tried casting class type and modified class structure to follow `Java.Lang.Object` but none worked. Following is the source code that I am using:

```
        HomePojo mHomePojo = null;
        Gson mGson = new Gson();

        try
        {
            JSONObject dataObject = jObject.GetJSONObject(AppGlobal.TAG_JSON_DATA_OBJECT);
            com.greatlocations.pojos.HomePojo clazz = new com.greatlocations.pojos.HomePojo();
            mHomePojo = mGson.FromJson(dataObject.ToString(), Java.Lang.Class.FromType(clazz.GetType()));

        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.Write(e.StackTrace);
        }
```

Below is the `HomePojo` class:

```
public class HomePojo :  Java.Lang.Object
        {
    public string name;
    public string latitude;
    public string longitude;
    public string imageUrl;
    public string addsUrl;
    public string thumbnailURL;
    public string addsImage;

    public string greetings;

    public string description;


    public int id;


    java.util.ArrayList<>();
    public List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
    java.util.ArrayList<>();
    public List<AreaInfo> areaInfoArrayList = new List<AreaInfo>();
    }
```

This line,

```
mHomePojo = mGson.FromJson(dataObject.ToString(), Java.Lang.Class.FromType(clazz.GetType()));
```

is throwing Error

> Cannot implicitly convert type. An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

Comment: do ur `mHomePojo` and `clazz` variables belong to the same `HomePojo` class?

Comment: akg179, Yes they belong to the same HomePojo class

Comment: have u tried `mGson.FromJson(dataObject.ToString(), mHomePojo.Class)`?

Comment: @akg179 Yes, it throws the same error

Comment: I also used "mHomePojo = mGson.FromJson(dataObject.ToString(), Java.Lang.Class.FromType(mHomePojo.Class.GetType()));", but same error!

Comment: In the error message there should be the types for which the conversion is being tried. Can u please share from which `type` to which `type` is the the conversion being tried?

Comment: This is the full error message: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Java.Lang.Object' to 'com.greatlocations.pojos.HomePojo'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" com.greatlocations.pojos.HomePojo is the same class as HomePojo, mentioned above.

Comment: Have you tried removing '`Java.Lang.Object`' from base class declaration of `HomePojo` and then using `myHomePojo.Class` as an argument?

Comment: @akg179, No it did not work.

Comment: Can u debug and check what is the output of `Java.Lang.Class.FromType(clazz.GetType())` or 'HomePojo.Class`?

Comment: It's showing the same error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Java.Lang.Object' to 'com.greatlocations.pojos.HomePojo'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: is this the error just for the evaluation of `Java.Lang.Class.FromType(clazz.GetType())`?

Comment: i cast the `mGson.FromJson(dataObject.ToString(), Java.Lang.Class.FromType(clazz.GetType()))` to `HomePojo`,it didn't throw error,but always get `null`; maybe you could try to use Newtonsoft.Json nuget